# Input, select scale issue

Tags: html, css, select, input

When I almost finished my web design I runned into the scale problem. For example having 10 select boxes in a row and having wrapper around give perfect look until I start zooming out. Holding CTRL button and scrolling out it looks like the select list gives some padding and ruins perfect look. For example: select height:24px and it is in ul list with height of 40px and multiply by 10 gives me 400px height of wrapper but on zooming out it looks like 420px and overlaps box. I tried with position, display, float, web-kit ant other stuff  but it didn't worked. What problem can it be?
EDIT: 
    JSFiddle: `[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2vs0es/)`

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: That's a cool story. Without code.

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` on selects and remove margins.

Answer (score 0):

On the CSS, you wrote `slect` instead of `select`.

It seems pretty good to me now: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2vs0es/1/). 

**UPDATE:** It wasn't good enough, so I removed the fixed pixel height on the `ul` and `li`. Now it's perfect. If you want the list items to be taller you can just add padding to them.
[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2vs0es/2/).